# Two exact same queries perform different in different enviorment

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, partitioning, informatica

I'm using informatica mapping to process data in my DB, so I'll try to explain the logic in SQL .

I have a mapping that exchanges data from one environment to another(from my staging to my data Warehouse) . This basically does

```
INSERT INTO table (select ... from ...)
```

In informatica, there is an option to add partitions to the table, to speed up the process and run parallel.

Now to my issue:

I have created a session that exchange a table from one environment to another, divided to 4 partitions by the table key range , those are the queries being generated:

```
SELECT ....
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE MyTable.DWH_END_DATE =
       to_date('31/12/2999', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
   AND MyTable.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY >= 292000001  

  SAME QUERY
  """" AND  FCT_CUSTOMER_SERVICES.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY >= 282000001 AND FCT_CUSTOMER_SERVICES.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY < 292000000

  SAME QUERY
  """" AND FCT_CUSTOMER_SERVICES.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY >= 250000001 AND FCT_CUSTOMER_SERVICES.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY < 282000000

  SAME QUERY
  """"  AND FCT_CUSTOMER_SERVICES.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY < 250000000
```

This queries are running parrallel. Now the problem is: I first checked this on my DEVELOP environment (exact same data, table structure, indexes ETC..)

Each partition runs about 4 min with 5 million records(I can see each partition process separatly)

When I run the exact same thing on  my PRODUCTION enviroment - the first 3 partitions run exactly like in the dev, but the last one suddely slows down and run 10X more time then it should be(same amount of data, it just select and insert slower)

I'm talking about this one

```
MyTable.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY >= 292000001
```

I seriously have absolutely no idea what can cause this.. If all the partitions would be slower, then it could make sense but its basically a RANGE on WHERE clause, so it should perform exactly the same as another range(Yes, they have same amount in each range)

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans in both environments?

Comment: @AlexPoole Sadly it is not possible through informatica, but how and why this range will have different explain plans then other ranges? And only in the PROD environment and not in the DEV

Comment: You can query the execution plans with any Oracle SQL client

Comment: You should find out if the select or insert is causing the apparent slow-down. You might have high water mark issues affecting a full table/partition scan. Is the table actually partitioned into four, and why are you running four statements instead of a single one?

Comment: Its not devided into 4, its a way to speed up processes . The 4 queries run in parralel so its faster for big tables to do that. (It works fine when I do the same thing but use range on a different column) @AlexPoole

Comment: That's faster and more efficient that using the built-in [parallel execution capabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm)? This probably isn't relevant to your issue, it would just move whatever problem you're having, but it still looks a bit strange.

Comment: Its probably very much alike.. Yea I know, me and my coworkers are breaking our heads about it :| @AlexPoole

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate the plan , oracle takes into consideration a lot of different factors , more importantly statistics on the table, but also initialization parameters like optimizer mode, compatible, multiblock read count, index cost adj, etc... and even cpu cost and io cost, which may differ if Dev and Prod are different machines / storage.

Without looking at the actual plans it would be very difficult to tell what is happening, I suggest checking statistics on both tables and make sure they are identical, and also all initialization parameters which will affect the query. And you can always check the plans with a tool like sql plus or sql developer, and the right privileges

Comment: That doesn't explain how one range perform better then the other. Again, I understand how PROD can perform slower then DEV . But that only diffrence between the queries is the range in the where, which have the same amount of rows returned.

Comment: The explain plan of each range is the same, and there is statistics on the table, so how is it possible for one to perform slower?(I don't know if the slow part is in the insert or the select)

Comment: The explain may differ from the actual plan, so it would be best to check the actual plan using the sql_id . It could be caused if the statistics are off on that column, and the optimizer estimates that `MyTable.DWH_PRODUCT_KEY >= 292000001`  will return more than 1/4 of the data , and do a full instead of a range scan, but there is a lot of "assuming" here without looking at the actual plan and env. It should appear on explain plan, but it may not, so that's something to be aware